# New user asking multiple low quality questions about the same source material

Tags: discussion, new-users

In the last month (5 March - 4 April 2020), one user (with two different accounts) has asked nearly 50 questions about *The History of Spiritualism, Vol. I* by Arthur Conan Doyle. The questions can be found by searching for "http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks03/0301051h.html".

I have suggested to the user in a comment that the source material might be too far above their present level and that more contemporary books might be better to help them improve their English.

How can we help this user without cluttering up ELL with all these similar questions?

Answer (score 4):

We're a little late to the party (but I wasn't a ♦ moderator in April). The system has [blocked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/295232) the user from asking more questions, but they've managed to circumvent said blocks, up to the point where it qualifies as **abuse of the system**. You're welcome to flag these questions for moderator attention so that we can take action.

Comment: I actually started to see very low quality questions from low rep learners. **Especially after Covide-19 became a social concerns** Now, I have become to choose to look at the questions to look a the question is if it is either unique or quite helpful.